# MYSQL split values to multiple rows based on Quantity

Tags: mysql

I am a newbie in mysql. 
I have table :

```
mros    | part_no   | qty
01      | aaa       | 2    
01      | bbb       | 2
02      | aaa       | 1  
03      | ccc       | 3
```

I want output like this :

```
mros    | part_no   | qty
01      | aaa       | 1
01      | aaa       | 1    
01      | bbb       | 1
01      | bbb       | 1
02      | aaa       | 1  
03      | ccc       | 1
03      | ccc       | 1
03      | ccc       | 1
```

I don't know what mysql function name to do it.
So how can i do this using mysql query or what will be the best way to do it?

Comment: Could you add a little more detail in the tables? Your first table shows two `part_no` with the value `aaa` but different quantity's, but in output there's three different `aaa`'s, are these all the same product or different variants?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, as you can see the value aaa is the same product but different mros.

Comment: It would not be simple to do that direct in a SQL. There is no sql function to do it. You will either create a stored procedure/function in the database to do so or do it in your application layer.

Comment: It could be done in SQL if mysql supported `with` with a CTE (I think it don't, at least not until 5.7)

Comment: @ecos301, Actually I didn't get what's your need. Can you share more about it? Maybe I can give you a better solution.

Comment: @Vignesh, i need to 'unvipot' table based on part_no and qty. For each part_no with qty > 1 will create new row that contain same data. Sorry for unclear my question.